# SvelteKit: How to protect routes with localStorage?

Tags: javascript, typescript, sveltekit

So I made a `+page.ts` to protect my routes like so, but get localStorage is not defined?

```
import type { PageLoad } from "./$types"
import {redirect} from "@sveltejs/kit";
import axios from 'axios';


axios.interceptors.request.use(function (config) {
    let authToken = localStorage.getItem('auth_token');

    if (authToken !== null) {
        config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + authToken;
    }

    config.headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json";

    return config;
});

export const load: PageLoad = async () => {
    if (localStorage.getItem('auth_token') === null) {
        throw redirect(302, '/')
    }
    axios.get(import.meta.env.VITE_API_URL + '/auth/me')
        .then(function (response) {
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            localStorage.removeItem('auth_token')
            throw redirect(302, '/')
        });
}
```

Every single question I read mentions cookies, and its hard to know what to do when you aren't using said technology... I am using localStorage.

Answer (score 0):

You really should not use `localStorage` for that.

SvelteKit uses server-side rendering by default and you cannot access the browser's storage on the server, but you will get the cookies.

The only option when using a browser storage would be to [turn off server-side rendering](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/page-options#ssr). This is *not* recommended.